# Ideas On How Can I Make My Users To Navigate Between Different Quiz Type

Tags: android

```
First of all I will not post some code here because there is no idea to start with.

I'm planning on creating a quiz type app on android with different quiz type like 

identification, multiple choie, matching, fill-in-the-blanks, true/false etc. And divide 

them into different parts of the quiz for e.g. for Test I. Identification, Test II. Multiple

 Choice and so on.. I will also give the user the capability of going back to previous parts 

of the exam for e.g. I'm currently on Test III. and suddenly I got an answer for a question 

from Test I., I can easily go back to that question and answer it.
```

**Current ideas so far:**

```
1. Create an app that implements ViewPager. Different quiz type on each pages?

2. Create a ListView put all the questions in there but all the questions are stil on their respective group first few questions is from Test I., Test II., etc. in their respective order.

Current problems encountered for the ideas above:

1. How can I submit the different forms from different pages on the ViewPager?

2. When the data contains a lot of questions the ListView will have a lot of scrolling 

between each questions. To solve this, I may create a floating-like navigation(I don't 

really have any idea on what to do with this) on the right side of the screen so that I can

 scroll instantly to Test I. with a click of a button.

*Please consider the ideas above noob-ish, I don't really know if some of the ideas that 

I'm talking about is possible or not, and please you may post the exact terminology on what

 you are talking about so that I can search it up.
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem at all... For instance... is Test 2 depending on Test 1, so that Test 1 has to be completed to access Test 2?

Comment: The test are not dependent on each other you can choose to skip Test 1 if you find the answer difficult. I'll put that on my question

Comment: Hm okay, so it is up to you what kind of navigation you prefer. Speaking for myself I would have chosen the `ViewPager` because the topic or content of the ViewPager's views are similar. They all contain quizzes.

Comment: Then the main problem will be is how can I combine all the answers from different page and send it to my web server as a JSON? I already know how to transform it into JSON and sends it to my web sever, I just need to combine the data into one and send it. I really don't have any idea on how to pass value from different fragments using ViewPager.

Comment: I don't know how your data model looks like but nevertheless you will have to use a sqlite database on the mobile device to store your data (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html). With AsyncTasks you can send your solitions/data to your webserver (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've decided to go with ViewPager in creating this app.

[ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)